# How can I make cards stack on the right and left of each other?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

I have to make a card with some words and image on it and store it as a component and then I have to call that component 3 times on `app.component.html` so that 3 of the cards will be shown on the site. Now the cards are stacking vertically below each other. How can I make them horizontally aligned?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img" src="assets/grey.jpg" alt="Grey backgroud">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Heading</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">View details »</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my SCSS code:

```
@import "../../styles";

.card{text-align: center;
    

    &-title{font: 32px -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    }

    &-text{font: 16px -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    }

    &-img{border-radius: 100%;
    width: 140px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap with col-md, col-lg... and the grid of bootstrap

Comment: actually it doesn't work...I know it works on html css and javascript but I'm still finding a way to make it work in angular

Comment: try this : https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/layout/grid-usage/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `card-group` or `card-deck` for horizontal card alignment.

card-group is no-space between the cards.

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
      <p class="card-text">...</p>
      <p class="card-text">...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or card-deck is given the equal space between cards.

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
      <p class="card-text">...</p>
      <p class="card-text">...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just use style

> display: flex

on the parent above `.card-deck` element.
By default, they will fall into a row.